# How to make this table aligned, centered and also fit into a page?

Tags: tables, excel2latex

I copied this table from excel2latex, I want this table to be centered, aligned and fit into the the page within the margin.
My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \small
    \scalebox{0.4}{
    \begin{tabular}{llcclccc}
        \textbf{Table 1} &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{Charitable Donation Tax Credit Rates1, by Province, 1997 and 2009 (\%)} \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c@{\quad}}{1997} &       & \multicolumn{3}{r@{\quad}}{2009} \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{6-8}          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{First \$200 of Donations} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Donation in Excess of \$200} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{First \$200 of Donations} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Donations in Excess of \$200} \\
        Federal & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{29.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{29.0} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Newfoundland and Labrador} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.73} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20.01} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.7} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15.5} \\
        Price Edward Island & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10.12} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17.26} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.8} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16.7} \\
        Nova Scotia & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.95} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16.97} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.79} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17.5} \\
        New Brunswick & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10.71} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{18.27} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.65} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17.95} \\
        Quebec2 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{23.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{23.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24.0} \\
        Ontario & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.16} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13.92} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6.05} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.16} \\
        Manitoba & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.5} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.5} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10.8} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17.4} \\
        Saskatchewan & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.4} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{16.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15.0} \\
        Alberta & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.74} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{13.20} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10.0} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{21.0} \\
        British Columbia & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.67} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.79} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.06} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.7} \\
        \midrule
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{8}{r}{1The credit rate is statutory rate, which is not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage of provincial/territorial income taxes net of the provincial/territorial Charitable Donation Tax Credit.} \\
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{2 The tax credit rate for Quebec residents must be adjusted for the 16.5\% Quebec Abatement.} \\
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Source: Canada Revenue Agency; Department of Finance Canada calculations.}} \\
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
}
\end{table}





\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making it to latex format! Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Try with `[!htpb]` after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: @Cragfelt that will have no effect at all on the tabular layout

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I was wrong. In that case it has to be  within `figure` environment. Right?

Comment: @Cragfelt -- regarding the positioning argument (the `[!htpb]`), this would be the same for either `table` or `figure`.  the problem is with the size of the table, not the location.

Comment: @Cragfelt no, the question is unrelated to the position of the table on the page, it is about the tabular itself, and how big it is.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, thank you. I did not analize the question profundly and mistaked the usage of those environments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, my bad. I did not read the question properly.

Answer (score 3):

the markup generated by excel2latex is just massively over-complicated, all the `\multicolumn{1}{c}` are doing nothing useful at all. Mostly here I just removed the markup added. It would be simpler to just get a plain text comma separated value output from excel and add the markup required, however

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\caption{Charitable Donation Tax Credit Rates1, by Province, 1997 and 2009 (\%)}


    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{S}@{}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1997} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2009} \\
        \cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}          
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{First \$200} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Excess of \$200} &       
\multicolumn{1}{l}{First \$200} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Excess of \$200} \\
        Federal & 17.0 & 29.0 & 15.0 & 29.0 \\
        \midrule
     Newfoundland \& Labrador & 11.73 & 20.01 & 7.7 & 15.5 \\
        Price Edward Island & 10.12 & 17.26 & 9.8 & 16.7 \\
        Nova Scotia & 9.95 & 16.97 & 8.79 & 17.5 \\
        New Brunswick & 10.71 & 18.27 & 9.65 & 17.95 \\
        Quebec2 & 23.0 & 23.0 & 20.0 & 24.0 \\
        Ontario & 8.16 & 13.92 & 6.05 & 11.16 \\
        Manitoba & 8.5 & 14.5 & 10.8 & 17.4 \\
        Saskatchewan & 9.4 & 16.0 & 11.0 & 15.0 \\
        Alberta & 7.74 & 13.20 & 10.0 & 21.0 \\
        British Columbia & 8.67 & 14.79 & 5.06 & 14.7 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%


    \begin{enumerate}
    \item  The credit rate is statutory rate, which is not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage of provincial/territorial income taxes net of the provincial/territorial Charitable Donation Tax Credit.
\item  The tax credit rate for Quebec residents must be adjusted for the 16.5\% Quebec Abatement.
    \end{enumerate}



 \textit{Source: Canada Revenue Agency; Department of Finance Canada calculations.}

\end{table}





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one. This one taking also in account simplify the design of awful headers (maybe is not what you want, but the point is catch the idea that headers with a lot of lines are not pleasing).  Indeed, this job is best done at hand, starting with a raw copy & paste for spreadsheet to the LaTeX editor or importing a .csv file that adapting the unnecessarily complicated `excel2latex` ouput.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{U}{S[table-format=4.3,round-mode=places, round-precision=2]}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\belowcaptionskip{1ex}
\begin{document}    
% Table generated by hand 1.0 from MWE 
\begin{table}
\caption{Charitable Donation Tax Credit Rates (\%)\protect\footnotemark[1], by Province.} 
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XUUUU@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Donations in 1997} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Donations in 2009} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-5}
 & \mbox{1st \$200} & 
\mbox{$>\mathdollar200$} &
\mbox{1st \$200} & 
\mbox{$>\mathdollar200$} \\
\midrule
        Federal &  17.0 & 29.0 & 15.0 & 29.0 \\
        Newfoundland and Labrador &  11.73 & 20.01 & 7.7 & 15.5 \\
        Price Edward Island &  10.12 & 17.26 & 9.8 & 16.7 \\
        Nova Scotia &  9.95 & 16.97 & 8.79 & 17.5 \\
        New Brunswick &  10.71 & 18.27 & 9.65 & 17.95 \\
        Quebec\footnotemark[2] &  23.0 & 23.0 & 20.0 & 24.0 \\
        Ontario &  8.16 & 13.92 & 6.05 & 11.16 \\
        Manitoba &  8.5 & 14.5 & 10.8 & 17.4 \\
        Saskatchewan &  9.4 & 16.0 & 11.0 & 15.0 \\
        Alberta &  7.74 & 13.20 & 10.0 & 21.0 \\
        British Columbia &  8.67 & 14.79 & 5.06 & 14.7 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\par\footnotesize\parskip1ex
\footnotemark[1] The credit rate is statutory rate, which is not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage of provincial/territorial income taxes net of the provincial/territorial Charitable Donation Tax.\par
\footnotemark[2] The tax credit rate for Quebec residents must be adjusted for the 16.5\% Quebec Abatement.\par
\emph{Source: Canada Revenue Agency; Department of Finance Canada calculations.}         
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

with use of `threeparttable`, `tablenotes` and `tabular*` environment::

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            labelsep=newline,
            singlelinecheck=false
            ]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Charitable Donation Tax Credit Rates\tnote{1}, by Province, 1997 and 2009 (\%)}
    \label{tab:addlabel}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \small
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l SSSS}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Donations in 1997}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Donations in 2009}      \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        &   {First \$200}
                &   {Excess of \$200}
                        &   {First \$200}
                                &   {Excess of \$200}               \\
Federal & 17.0  & 29.0  & 15.0  & 29.0                              \\
    \midrule
Newfoundland and Labrador
        & 11.73 & 20.01 & 7.7   & 15.5                              \\
Price Edward Island
        & 10.12 & 17.26 & 9.8   & 16.7                              \\
Nova Scotia
        & 9.95  & 16.97 & 8.79  & 17.5                              \\
New Brunswick
        & 10.71 & 18.27 & 9.65  & 17.95                             \\
Quebec\tnote{2} 
        & 23.0  & 23.0  & 20.0  & 24.0                              \\
Ontario & 8.16  & 13.92 & 6.05  & 11.16                             \\
Manitoba & 8.5  & 14.5  & 10.8  & 17.4                              \\
Saskatchewan
        & 9.4   & 16.0  & 11.0  & 15.0                              \\
Alberta & 7.74  & 13.20 & 10.0  & 21.0                              \\
British Columbia
        & 8.67  & 14.79 & 5.06  & 14.7                              \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[1]    The credit rate is statutory rate, which is not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage of provincial/territorial income taxes net of the provincial/territorial Charitable Donation Tax Credit.
\item[2]    The tax credit rate for Quebec residents must be adjusted for the \SI{16.5}{\%} Quebec Abatement.

    \smallskip
\item[]     \textit{Source: Canada Revenue Agency; Department of Finance Canada calculations.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's quite similar to the one by @Zarko (I swear I didn't copy his approaches!). The main differnces are (a) the use of a `tabularx` environment and (b) the material in the first column is subject to automatic line-breaking and -wrapping.

The number of columns has been reduced from 8 to 5, by eliminating the blank columns. All useless and pointless `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers have been discarded.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
                    \hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip,labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\begin{document}    

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Charitable Donation Tax Credit Rates\tnote{1}, 
         by Province, 1997 and 2009 (\%)}  
\label{tab:addlabel}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{1997} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{2009} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
& \mC{First \$200 of Donations}      
& \mC{Donations in Excess of \$200}      
& \mC{First \$200 of Donations}
& \mC{Donations in Excess of \$200} \\ 
\midrule
Federal & 17.0 & 29.0 & 15.0 & 29.0 \\
\addlinespace
Newfoundland and Labrador & 11.73 & 20.01 & 7.7 & 15.5 \\
Price Edward Island & 10.12 & 17.26 & 9.8 & 16.7  \\
Nova Scotia      &  9.95 & 16.97 &  8.79 & 17.5 \\
New Bruns\-wick    & 10.71 & 18.27 &  9.65 & 17.95 \\
Quebec\tnote{2}  & 23.0  & 23.0  & 20.0  & 24.0 \\
Ontario          &  8.16 & 13.92 &  6.05 & 11.16 \\
Manitoba         &  8.5  & 14.5  & 10.8  & 17.4 \\
Saskatche\-wan   &  9.4  & 16.0  & 11.0  & 15.0 \\
Alberta          &  7.74 & 13.20 & 10.0  & 21.0 \\
British Columbia &  8.67 & 14.79 &  5.06 & 14.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] The credit rate is statutory rate, which is 
not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value 
of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage 
of provincial\slash territorial income taxes net of 
the provincial\slash territorial Charitable Donation 
Tax Credit.
\item[2] The tax credit rate for Quebec residents 
must be adjusted for the 16.5\% Quebec Abatement.
\end{tablenotes}

\textit{Source: Canada Revenue Agency; Department 
of Finance Canada calculations.}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `threeparttable`, `siunitx`, `colortbl` and `siunitx`. I redesigned it a bit;

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, makecell, caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\captionsetup{labelsep = newline, labelfont = bf, font = small, singlelinecheck = off}
\begin{table}
  \centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \small
\caption{Charitable Donation Tax Credit Rates1, by Province, 1997 and 2009 (\%)}
\rowcolors{4}{WhiteSmoke!70!Lavender}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{3}{Sc}S}%
        \toprule
        \midrule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c@{\quad}}{1997} & & \multicolumn{2}{r@{\quad}}{2009} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){6-8} &{ \makecell{First \$\,200\\ of Donations}} & & {\makecell{Donation\\ in Excess\\ of \$\,200}} & & {\makecell{First \$\,200\\ of Donations}} & & {\makecell{Donations\\ in Excess\\ of \$\,200}} \\
\addlinespace
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!60!Lavender} Federal & 17.0 & & 29.0 & & 15.0 & & 29.0 \\
        \addlinespace
        Newfoundland and Labrador & 11.73 & & 20.01 & & 7.7 & & 15.5 \\
        Price Edward Island & 10.12 & & 17.26 & & 9.8 & & 16.7 \\
        Nova Scotia & 9.95 & & 16.97 & & 8.79 & & 17.5 \\
        New Brunswick & 10.71 & & 18.27 & & 9.65 & & 17.95 \\
        Quebec2 & 23.0 & & 23.0 & & 20.0 & & 24.0 \\
        Ontario & 8.16 & & 13.92 & & 6.05 & & 11.16 \\
        Manitoba & 8.5 & & 14.5 & & 10.8 & & 17.4 \\
        Saskatchewan & 9.4 & & 16.0 & & 11.0 & & 15.0 \\
        Alberta & 7.74 & & 13.20 & & 10.0 & & 21.0 \\
        British Columbia & 8.67 & & 14.79 & & 5.06 & & 14.7 \\
        \midrule
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tablenotes}
 \item[1.]The credit rate is statutory rate, which is not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage of provincial/territorial income taxes net of the provincial/territorial Charitable Donation Tax Credit.
 \item[2.]The credit rate is statutory rate, which is not subject to surtaxes. Surtaxes increase the value of the credit as they are calculated as a percentage of provincial/territorial income taxes net of the provincial/territorial Charitable Donation Tax Credit.\smallskip
\item[]\textit{Source: Canada Revenue Agency; Department of Finance Canada calculations.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]